# Singleton in python

Tags: python, singleton

I have seen the post about implementing Singletons in python, but I wanted to see if I could do it on my own. With that being said I ended up with this:

```
class Singleton:
     instance = None
     def __init__(self, attribute):
           if instance is None:
                self.attribute = attribute
                Singleton.instance = self
           else:
                self = instance

s1 = Singleton("s1")
s2 = Singleton("s2")
print(s1 is s2)
```

The print statement will print out False, but I am not sure why it is not True as I would think they both point to Singleton.

Comment: Replacing `self` will only give the variable a new value. It will not replace the instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, your code with a undefined val 'instance'. Maybe you need to write 'Singleton.instance'.
2. in line 8, you can not change original self val, just create a new val is named self. So print(s1 is s2) will be False.

I write a new code, wish to help you:

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __init__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if not hasattr(cls, '_instance'):
            orig = super(Singleton, cls)
            cls._instance = orig.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
        return cls._instance

s1 = Singleton("s1")
s2 = Singleton("s2")
print(s1 is s2)
```

Comment: I believe you need to change to this line `cls._instance = orig.__new__(cls)` without passing `*args` and `**kw`